# Log4j : How do I lookup the datasource in log4jconf.xml

Tags: log4j, appender

I am using weblogic for application deployment and I have created a datasource with jndi name "MyDataSource". when I try to use it in my log4j configuration, it is not working

```
<appender name="myDbAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender">
  <param name="jndiName" value="MyDataSource"/>     
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
   <param name="ConversionPattern" value="INSERT INTO LOGGING (user_id,  
        correlation_id, first_name, last_name, event_name, role, 
        status, access_level, message, logger, loglevel) 
        VALUES ( '%X{USER_ID}', '%X{CORRELATION_ID}', '%X{FIRST_NAME}',
        '%X{LAST_NAME}','%X{EVENT_NAME}','%X{ROLE}','%X{STATUS}','%X     
       {ACCESS_LEVEL}',
         '%m' , '%X{LOGGER}','%p' )"/>
</layout>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this feature, you need to add the jar file of [Apache Extras for Apache log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/) and use the class [**`org.apache.log4j.DBAppender`**](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DBAppender.html). e.g.:

```xml
<!-- console -->
<appender name="STDOUT" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout" />
</appender>

<!-- db -->
<appender name="DBOUT" class="org.apache.log4j.DBAppender">
    <connectionSource class="org.apache.log4j.receivers.db.JNDIConnectionSource">
        <param name="jndiLocation" value="java:/comp/env/jdbc/MySQLDS" />
    </connectionSource>
</appender>

<!-- root -->
<root>
    <priority value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="DBOUT" />
</root>
```